# Fastest way to read file searching for pattern matches

Tags: python, grep

I made a python script to analyze logs. I have one observation to share, and two questions to ask.

When I use gzip.open to open each file and go through every line, it takes around 200 seconds just to going through all the lines and files.

```
with gzip.open(file) as fp:
    for line in fp:
          pass
```

If using `zcat` and `grep` to do the work, it takes about 50 seconds.

```
temp = commands.getstatusoutput("zcat file* | grep pattern")
```

The performance difference is too huge to ignore. Is there a better way to reduce the gap?

I also noticed that the `commands` module is made obsolete by the `subprocess` module, which seems always create a temporary file. But it wouldn't be convenient, what if it is not possible to create a temporary file from where the python script is running? Any suggestion?

Comment: I doubt the difference is just in iteration. What are you doing with each line inside that loop?

Comment: Remember that `grep` uses some extremely polished code-generation techniques to optimise its speed. It may be old, but that doesn't mean it's bad - in this case, quite the opposite. You could spend decades of work trying to match its speed, and not come close, because the people who made it are very, very smart. (e.g. see https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html)

Comment: On the offchance that the Python 'for' loop shown above really is empty, and the speed difference is caused by differences between zcat and Python's gzip: You could try an experiment. What happens if you unzip the file manually, and then replace Python's 'gzip.open' with regular 'open'. That might shed some light on what is causing the slowdown.

Comment: I've modified my post. I originally try to find some patterns. Later, for benchmarking purpose, I put on "pass" to measure the time.

Comment: @Jonathan Hartley I liked your suggestion of removing the influence of gzip.open and zcat. I unzipped the .log.gz files and compared the speed. The result is using python to go through each line takes 36 seconds, while using grep takes 6.5 seconds.

Comment: @Sarah Nice one. That makes it sound like the slowdown isn't introduced by unzipping the file, but instead by whatever is happening inside the for loop.

Comment: I just thought of something: Even if the for loop is empty, 'grep' might still be faster. Grep doesn't actually read the file one line at a time and then search each line for the pattern. It turns out to be faster to simply ignore newlines and jump through the file a calculated number of bytes at a time, looking for any character that might match any part of the pattern, ignoring newlines altogether. Then when it finds a match, it searches around to look for reqd newlines. This is one of many speed optimisations in grep...

Comment: ...Hence, in any programming language, not just Python, it's going to be a lot of work to match the speed of grep.

Comment: If using system calls to 'grep' really is faster (which I'm starting to believe it really is), and this is important for you, then personally I'd strongly consider just calling 'grep', using the command you show. But I would use 'subprocess', rather than 'commands'. Subprocess shouldn't have any problems doing this. I will refrain from showing the exact invocation, because it varies a lot depending on what version of Python you are using. If you let us know that, I'll add an answer which calls subprocess to do this.

Comment: I don't think subprocess should need to create a temporary file. Do you mean you cannot put the shown command into subprocess, because it won't let you pipe between two commands using '|' ? If you wish to do this using subprocess, you must use 'shell=True', so that it passes your command to a shell to interpret it, which knows how to do pipes and the like. (as opposed to simply looking for a single executable of the name given in your command and executing it)

Comment: ...or do you mean you cannot get the output of your 'grep' command out of subprocess, to analyze it in Python? That can be done. Let me know your version of Python and I'll show how.

Comment: **Downvoters**: This question has been substantially improved. Personally I'd reconsider whether downvotes are appropriate.

Comment: @Jonathan Hartley From my current understanding, if using subprocess, I'd have to first create a file and direct the output to the file before processing as shown below (sorry that I can't modify the format much in comments). I really want to avoid the step of a temporary file... tempfile=open('temp.out','w+')
output1, errors1 = subprocess.Popen(['zcat file* | grep pattern'], shell=True, stdout=tempfile).communicate()

Comment: @Sarah Ah, I see what you mean. I bet there's a way to sidestep that. I'll have a play, see if I can find a way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'grep' contains decade's worth of optimizations, and re-implementing it in any programming language, not just Python, will be slower. *1

Therefore, if speed is important to you, your technique of calling 'grep' directly is probably the way to go. To do this using 'subprocess', without having to write any temporary files, use the 'subprocess.PIPE' mechanism:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

COMMAND = 'zcat file* | grep oldconfig'
process = Popen(COMMAND, shell=True, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
output, errors = process.communicate()
assert process.returncode == 0, process.returncode
assert errors == '', errors
print('{} lines match'.format(len(output.splitlines())))
```

This works for me on Python3.5. I've avoided using any of the higher-level interfaces added on top of subprocess recently, so it should work fine on older versions of Python too.

---

(*1 for example, even with an empty 'for' loop, as you show in your question, grep is likely to still be faster, because it does not read the input line-by-line. Instead it determine the max number of characters it can seek forwards through the file, ignoring newlines completely, reading one char after each seek, searching for chars that might match any part of the regex. Only if it finds a match does it then look at the characters surrounding that match, to see if the rest of the regex matches and appropriate newlines are present. On top of that it dynamically generates code that is hard-coded to check for matches to the given regex, meaning it executes around 3 x86 instructions per input byte that it examines, and it skips examining most input bytes completely)