# Slashes in grep search string called from Python

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, grep, popen

I have the following input file "testFile.txt":

```
$ cat testFile.txt
111     // mNx
222     // mNy not nMx
333     // mNz also not nMx
```

I want to get the value of mNx, but some of the other lines contain comments about mNx. Using grep on the Unix command line to find the correct line:

```
$ grep mNx testFile.txt
111     // mNx
222     // mNy not mNx
333     // mNz also not mNx
```

However,

```
$ grep "// mNx" testFile.txt
111     // mNx
```

OK, so far so good, but I want to call grep using Python. Following on from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153471/fastest-way-to-read-file-searching-for-pattern-matches) I have

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
def grep1(inFile, string):
    COMMAND = 'grep %s %s' % (string, inFile)
    process = Popen(COMMAND, shell=True, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    output, errors = process.communicate()
    return output

mNx = grep1('testFile.txt', 'mNx')
print mNx
```

which gives

```
111     // mNx
222     // mNy not mNx
333     // mNz also not mNx
```

Now if I instead use

```
mNx = grep1('testFile.txt', '// mNx')
```

it returns the following:

```
testFile.txt:111     // mNx
testFile.txt:222     // mNy not mNx
testFile.txt:333     // mNz also not mNx
```

I have tried `"\/\/ mNx"`, `r"// mNx"`, `r"\/\/ mNx"` etc., but cannot reproduce the native `grep` behaviour. Is something being escaped here in my Python string? What is going on?

Comment: @Inian thanks for the suggestion but this does not work.

Comment: What is the exact value you need, you need the number or the entire matching line?

Comment: I will eventually split the string, but this question is asking for the correct line only :)

Comment: @Inian I will do `mNx = int(grep1("testFile.txt", r'"// mNx"').split()[0])` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function call to `mNx = grep1('testFile.txt', '"// mNx"')`.

The thing is, we need the COMMAND to be this Python String Literal `'grep "// mNx" testFile.txt'`

You need to escape only if it is `\`. `/` can be represented as is in Python.

Comment: It will be interesting to know why we need it this way though.

Comment: Such a simple solution and solved the intended question, thanks. You are right, without these outer quotes then COMMAND would be `'grep // mNx testFile.txt'`.

Comment: With the original COMMAND line, grep searches for the string "//" in two files, "mNx" (doesn't exist) and "testFile.txt" (exists). Hence the output includes the filename on all matching lines to indicate which file it was found in. @Nishant